# Android : How to get new feed user's using graph in new Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I want get new feed user's but many the tutorial not working in new Facebook API.
I had login and post comment but i don't know continue get new feed in app Android.
I try in URL [ttps://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN](https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=CAAMelCtlrUUBAMlu2WRHD1XslQYusfZCNILvCCS9UNCvXth7F6stdl9WFA363BogWZC5eMyIoAskWdu5CqWV4QFIVOZBnR5pUAq7clrQU8Lscfq5xrpqpPvTC6wDTjazouxioPeZCu91ZA3Hg2WlZBeH56IIlHZA1dfrYudaT1sSDOns8PHQdPAmhP2sercwHhSuPSv5vngizlThPnmxA75) but return no.
And  [https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN](https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=CAAMelCtlrUUBAMlu2WRHD1XslQYusfZCNILvCCS9UNCvXth7F6stdl9WFA363BogWZC5eMyIoAskWdu5CqWV4QFIVOZBnR5pUAq7clrQU8Lscfq5xrpqpPvTC6wDTjazouxioPeZCu91ZA3Hg2WlZBeH56IIlHZA1dfrYudaT1sSDOns8PHQdPAmhP2sercwHhSuPSv5vngizlThPnmxA75) then error read_stream. But i had set read_stream premission read_stream. Somebody help me! I need some code but docs developer facebook's is simple so i don't understand.

Sorry my English not good !

Comment: Could you provide code that you have tried so far? It is easier to fix code you have started than request new code from scratch.

Comment: read_stream will only work for app admins, and will not get approved for web apps. see changelog about app reviews: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

> read_stream - This permission is reserved for apps that replicate the Facebook client on platforms that don’t have a native client.

"no native client" means devices like TVs and stuff.

So this permission will only work for App Admins, most permissions need to get approved now, see changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Afaik it is not possible to get access to the user feed anymore (except for App Admins, of course), unless you are creating an App for specific devices.